# Snippet tab completion which includes space

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I'm trying to make a snippet that will trigger on a text block which includes space, i.e. after typing `ALTER AGGREGATE` and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> I'd like snippet to trigger:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[triggered]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>ALTER AGGREGATE</tabTrigger>
</snippet>
```

But unfortunately this doesn't work.

I then tried to use escape for space: `<tabTrigger>ALTER&#160;AGGREGATE</tabTrigger>`, but that didn't work too.

Is this possible at all?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not. Snippets trigger on certain words, which in regex language excludes spaces as well as tabs and newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Snippet tab triggers unfortunately can't contain anything that is considered to be a word-separator by Sublime Text.

However, it is possible to emulate this trigger with a keybinding, if you want to keep the trigger text in the document:

```
{ "keys": ["tab"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": { "name": "Packages/User/alter_aggregate.sublime-snippet" },
    "context":
    [
        { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_match", "operand": "\\bALTER AGGREGATE$", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_match", "operand": "^$", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.sql", "match_all": true },
    ]
},
```

this assumes you have saved the snippet in your `Packages/User` folder with the name `alter_aggregate.sublime-snippet`.

example snippet content (note it is missing `ALTER AGGREGATE` but starts with a space:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
 ${1:myavg(integer)} RENAME TO ${2:newname};
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <!-- <tabTrigger>hello</tabTrigger> -->
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>source.sql</scope>
</snippet>
```

Then, typing `ALTER AGGREGATE` <kbd>Tab</kbd> will give you:

```
ALTER AGGREGATE myavg(integer) RENAME TO newname;
```

with the selection initially over `myavg(integer)` and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> will move it to `newname`, for convenience.